# Xcode 6.1 auto generating XC Ad Hoc

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My Xcode suddenly generates it's own provisioning profile for Ad Hoc. My ad hoc profiles are all fine but when I'm creating an archive now xcode just generate it's own profile. I don't know what caused the problem.

Here's the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

[image]

and when I try to export it again.. it will automatically choose the generated profile
[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all XC generated profile from member center along with my apps profile and generated a new one and my problem is solved.

NOTE: Clean Refresh Xcode's provisioning profile:

1.) Users ▸ username ▸ Library ▸ MobileDevice ▸ Provisioning Profile > DELETE all profile

2.) Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details > click the refresh button of provisioning